# Using Filters to match and preventing incorrect data due to blank cells

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, indexing, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I'm attempting to match data from two different sheets and bring in a list of company names from that matching row

```
A1:A1000 = List of Companies
E1:E5000 = List of Matchable IDs
C1 = Manually Input ID
```

The following macro works:

`=IFERROR(FILTER('List Companies'!A1:A1000,'List Companies'!E1:E1000='ID Sheet'!C1),"")`

However if C9 is blank it returns an incorrect list.

If I try and use the following:

`=IF(ISBLANK('ID Sheet'!C1), "", IFERROR(FILTER('List Companies'!A1:A1000,'List Companies'!E1:E1000='ID Sheet'!C1),""))`

It returns:

`"~ERROR"`

I'm sure I must be doing something wrong but I don't know what I am doing wrong... if anyone could point out my mistake I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: There are many typos in your question, although they are not critical. Please share a copy of your sheet.

Comment: I agree with the contributor above. You mention C9, but I think you mean C1. And there are no "macros" in your post, only formulas. Since we can't see the spreadsheet layout, data, data types, the exact nature of the error, etc., it would be thrashing in the dark to try to guess at what the issue may be. In the interest of efficiency, do consider sharing a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it), so that we can see and test the issue live and in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` it.

if C1 is manual input of ID then:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP('ID Sheet'!C1, {'List Companies'!E:E, 'List Companies'!A:A}, 2, 0))
```